# Deploying Different Functions Depending on if the Second is Even or Odd

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a function that will depend on whether the time in seconds is currently even or currently odd.  For some reason the pop-up is always giving me an “Odd” pop-up.  I have a couple ideas of why that is, but I haven’t been able to fix it.  Do you have any suggestions?  Thanks for the help.

```
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Seconds</button>
<p id="seconds"></p>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
  var date = new Date();
  var seconds = date.getUTCSeconds();
  document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
  }
function checkEven(seconds){
  return(seconds%2 == 0);
}
if(checkEven(seconds)){
  alert("Even");
}
else{
  alert("Odd");
}
</script>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `if` and `else` within `myFunction()`. Otherwise they only get called once.

```
function myFunction() {
  var date = new Date();
  var seconds = date.getUTCSeconds();
  if(checkEven(seconds)){
    alert("Even");
  }
  else{
    alert("Odd");
  }
  document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
}
function checkEven(seconds){
  return(seconds%2 == 0);
}
```

And when they get run that first time `seconds` isn't set so it will always fail the even check.

Comment: Thank you so much!  You are a lifesaver.  The force will be with you, always.

Comment: No problem! Could you mark my answer correct pretty please? People should know if this works and I want that tasty reputation.